# A digital signature does not require entering a pin after the first signature

Tags: c#, digital-signature, windows-security

I'm currently working on digital signing, and I have the problem, when I sign a document for the first time, the windows security smart card popup asks for a pin, the next time I want to sign another document with the same certificate, the popup doesn't pop up, and sign the document without entering the pin. However, when I close the application, and open it again and go to sign, Windows security pops up and asks for a pin. It's like he saved the pin somewhere in cache or session.
If the pin is saved in the session or in the cache memory, is it possible to clear the session or the cache memory, so that the next time the windows security popup requests the pin?
Thanks,
Andrijana

I expect a correct answer in order to fix my application

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. At the moment you've shown us no code at all, which makes it really, really hard to help.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [how to ask.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and add some details to your question to help in finding an answer.

Comment: I found out that this is the standard behavior of the Windows Security Smart Card dialog.